# Folder handle not released after Dir checks for existence

Tags: vba, outlook

The following code checks to see if a folder exists and, if not, creates it. The code works, but a handle that points to the folder is left open if it already exists, which prevents the folder from being deleted or renamed until `Outlook.exe` closes. I do not understand why this is happening or what to do about it, but a handle should not be open after the folder is checked and potentially created.

```
Sub Test()
    Folder = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\NewFolder\"
    Result = Dir(Folder, vbDirectory)
    If Result = vbNullString Then
        MkDir Folder
    End If
End Sub
```

The first time through the code, the folder is successfully created and no file handles are open:

[image]

However, the second time through the code, the folder already exists. `MkDir` does not execute, but a file handle is left open presumably after `Dir` executes:

[image]

I have tried everything I could find to close all open file handles, but nothing has worked. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I just tried your code and it works fine, and I can delete it no problem as well. What OS are you using?

Comment: Just for testing your theory, run the Dir function again afterwards on a bogus folder name. Any difference?

Comment: @braX Interestingly, adding this line after the `End If` statement releases the file handle: `FileName = Dir(Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\ASDF123456\", vbDirectory)`, which does not exist. This is in W10 Pro 64 bit with Office 365 / Outlook v1911 64 bit.

Comment: @braX More importantly, that solved the issue of not being able to delete the folder in the real script. I added a bogus `Dir` call at the end of the sub and I was immediately able to delete the folder without closing Outlook. I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Well, if it helps, I'm using W10 Pro 64 too, but Office 2016

Comment: Another thing to try would be to use a FileSystem object instead of Dir to see if you can avoid using the kludge of calling Dir a second time.

Comment: @braX Using an FSO solved the issue without the kludge. Good idea and thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments from braX, I was able to prove that the `Dir` call was somehow responsible for the leftover handle. Calling `Dir` again on a non-existent folder caused the handle to be released, which solved my problem.

A better solution, which was also suggested by braX, is to use a `File System Object`. Here is a working solution:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim FSO As FileSystemObject
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Folder = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\NewFolder\"
    If Not FSO.FolderExists(Folder) Then
        MkDir Folder
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks, braX!

Comment: As a side note, you could also use the FileSystem Object to create the folder instead of using that old fashioned MkDir

Comment: I see. Thanks for the heads up.